# SQL return optimal value if

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working with a database in which a table like the one below appears.

```
 StudentNum  |    Coin
-------------+------------
     1       |    Heads
     1       |    Tails
     3       |    Tails
     3       |    Tails
     2       |    Heads
     3       |    Tails
```

I do not have permissions to add or adjust the table, and need to know if it's possible to control the conditions on which rows are populated when I join this to another table.

Specifically, I am trying to find if each given ID has obtained a positive result (in this case Tails) at least once. If so, use that for the field, otherwise use Heads.

```
 StudentID   |    Coin   |    ...
-------------+-----------+----------
     1       |    Tails  |
     2       |    Heads  |
     3       |    Tails  |
     4       |     ...   |
    ...      |     ...   |
```

Comment: `has obtained a positive result (in this case Tails)` - you mean Heads, right?

Comment: If at least one of the results in the first table comes up Tails, I want to use the value Tails in the bottom table. I only want Heads to be used where all corresponding values in the top table are Heads.

Comment: I'm fairly new to this whole thing, so if this answer isn't quite right I do apologize, but I'm using Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CASE WHEN statement. See if this is what you want.

```
SELECT distinct a.StudentID,
                b.Coin

FROM table a
Join ( Select Student ID, 
               CASE WHEN Coin = 'Tails' then 'Tails'
               Else 'heads'
               END Coin
        From table ) b on b.student_id = a.student_id
```

Comment: I like how your explanation addresses the Join, but I'm still get cases where I have duplicate values under StudentID, one with Heads and one with Tails.

Comment: Help me understand the end result. Is the goal to have unique ID's and if they have a 'Tails' then display only their ID with Tails. What happens if they have both? Like in the sample above, StudentNum = 1. What would you like to see?

Comment: I want to Join the top table with another table so that each StudentID is used no more than once. If any of the top table's StudentNum have a Tails, I want the bottom table to use Tails in its corresponding spot. The only place where Heads should be used in the bottom table is when none of the corresponding StudentNum in the top table have a Tails.

Comment: I was tinkering around with your code a little bit and ended up getting the results that I wanted. What I changed was ||||||||||

b.coin -> CASE WHEN a.Coin = 'Tails' THEN 'Tails' ELSE 'Heads' END, 
||||||||||
Join ( Select Student ID, -> LEFT JOIN (SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN (Coin = 'Tails') THEN StudentID ELSE NULL END AS char) AS StudentID,
||||||||||
From table ) b on b.student_id = a.student_id -> FROM b) b ON b.StudentID = a.StudentNum 
||||||||||
Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand, you can use something like this:

```
select StudentNum, case when sum(case when Coin = 'Tails' then 1 end) >= 1 then 'Tails' else 'Heads' end
from the_table
group by StudentNum
```

Answer (score 0):

If coin only has `Heads` or `Tails` literally, then as `Tails` > `Heads` while doing string comparison, you can just use `max` and `group by`

```
select StudentNum  ,max(coin) as coin
from your_table
group by StudentNum;
```

So if for any student, you have both `Heads` and `Tails` or just `Tails` , you will get `Tails` as `MAX(COIN)`. If only `Head` then you will `Head`.

Limitation: Assuming no `null` or leading white spaces in `coin`. Also the case of both type of coin should be same (lower,UPPER or first Upper and then lower as comparison would happen on ascii value of first character.